# View SQL prepared with sp_prepare

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am troubleshooting an application that uses a SQL Server database and I am seeing a lot of `sp_execute` calls.

I can not seem to find the `sp_prepare` calls.

How can you inspect all of the prepared SQL statements in memory?

Comment: Are you actually using the sql profiler?

Comment: It would be [a normal/desirable state of affairs](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/forum/threads/sp_prepare-and-sp_execute.14685/) to have many more `sp_execute` calls in the trace files than `sp_prepare` calls.  As for finding the (parameterized) SQL tied to prepared handles, I would look through schemas of SQL Server system tables for columns named "handle" or "query plan" kinds of things.

Answer (score 14):

I was looking for a way to see the actual SQL statements executed by sp_execute in SQL Server 2008 R2 Profiler.

To do this, I created a new trace, and clicked on the "Events Selection" tab. I selected "Show all events" and checked Stored Procedures > SP:StmtCompleted. Running the trace, I was then able to see the actual SQL statements.

Answer (score 8):

I ran into this issue as well.  SQL Profiler was not capturing the `sp_prepare` statement because it occurred before the SQL Profiler trace had started to run.  The various postings that rely on `sys.dm_exec_sql_text` did not help because I could not find the correct `sql_handle` or `plan_handle` value to provide for that stored procedure.

I found a solution from [this blog post](http://performancetestersdiary.wordpress.com/2013/07/01/getting-the-sql-from-a-sp_execute-statement-in-microsoft-sql-profiler/): in SQL Profiler, click the "**Show all events**" checkbox and then under the "**Stored Procedures**" heading choose "**SP:CacheHit**".

In the resulting SQL Profiler output, you'll see an "**SP:CacheHit**" row containing the cached SQL statement near your "**RPC:Starting ... sp_execute**" statement.

You can then reconstruct and reexecute the full SQL statement in SSMS if you wish using:

```
exec sp_executesql @stmt=N'{statement from SP:CacheHit}', 
  @params=N'{parameter declaration from  SP:CacheHit}',
  @param1={value}, {...parameters from RPC:Starting sp_execute statement}
```

Answer (score 2):

Following up on my comment above, I found a number of relevant links:

[How can I find out what command sp_execute is running (without using Profiler)](http://dbaspot.com/ms-sqlserver/141465-how-can-i-find-out-what-command-sp_execute-running-without-using-profiler.html)

[SP_EXECUTE executing... what?](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic358301-146-1.aspx)

[See the query in sp_execute](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1099625-146-1.aspx)

Microsoft has documentation but it maybe a challenging piecing things together (as always).  If the plan handle is known, you can use this:

[sys.dm_exec_sql_text (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181929.aspx)

This is a table-valued function.  You can see [a blog article here](http://sqlserver-qa.net/blogs/t-sql/archive/2010/01/26/6256.aspx) that exploits such table-valued functions to retrieve object dependencies for a valid handle of a compiled (prepared) plan.